# PlayerPrefs not saving on Android/iOS Phone but saving on Unity Editor

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 5 on iMAC.
I have faced strange but true unknown issue with player prefs.

Issue :

On Unity Editor -
I have stored integer value in player prefs that works fine in UnityEditor, and when i restart my game in unityEditor then It was saved and i can retrieve that older saved player prefs's value.

On Android/iOS Device -
I have run that same code with device then behaviour will changed.During running game player prefs works fine and i can set and get that value.
But when i restart the game then i lost that value and can't retrieve that saved value another time.

I am tired to solve that issue, but i can't get success.

Anyone know solution about this unknowing behaviour of player prefs ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: may be we can spot the issue, if you share some code.

Comment: I am having the same issue as well.
Bought a game template from the Unity Asset store, using Unity 5.2 and OS X Captain.

Answer (score 3):

Do you use `PlayerPrefs.Save()`  after putting data?

If not read about it http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.Save.html

Comment: I think there can be 2 problems. 1. When Save function get called it writes file to disk and when application started it reads from disk, so the problem can come from disk or file. 2. The problem is logical, for example` somewhere you called DeleteAll or DeleteKey function

Comment: #haksist>> Thank you so much for your replay. Now i try to trash my code deeply. Another one is that as per your answer(2nd problem) -> If i DeleteAll or DeleteKey function, Then it should not be worked in UnityEditor :) :). But it's worked fine in UnityEditor and save and retrieve all the Key and Values. Only in Android/iOS device not saving those some playerprefs key and value.

Comment: #haksist >> I have used some another player prefs also but those all works fine only some of the key and values are not saved on only real devices And i also have tested in simulators also . Same problem i was faced in simulator also.

Comment: My code didn't have the Save() indeed. I added it after every single Set() method and... nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

You can circumvent this, by using your own file/serialization solution. For example protobuf. You can read an excellent guide [here](http://purdyjotut.blogspot.gr/2013/10/using-protobuf-in-unity3d.html).